# Conditional operator inside a React Native Tag

Tags: javascript, react-native, conditional-operator

React native beginner here.
I have a button in which the text will be changed depending on a condition.

So if "this.props.X ==='a'" the button text will be 'start',
if this.props.X ==='b' the button text will be 'stop'. How can I do that?
Can I use conditional operator inside the button tag?

I am trying like this but not working.

```
<Button 
  type = "primary"
  (this.props.X === 'a'? title = {'Start'} : title = {'Stop'})
 > 
</Button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to put the conditional check inside the value of the prop:

```
title={this.props.X === 'a' ? 'Start' : 'Stop'}
```

The value of a prop can either be a static value or the result of an expression, if you put that expression inside braces (`{...}`).